# Como compartilhar acesso entre diretivas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como posso chamar uma diretiva, dentro de uma segunda diretiva?

Eu tenho uma variável x na diretiva 1 e quero acessar essa variável `x` numa diretiva 2 para que eu possa dizer que `x (diretiva 1) === y (diretiva 2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira recomendada é [implementando um serviço](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) que você deve injetar nas diretivas/controles onde deseja compartilhar sua variável. (A idéia é que você possa compartilhar o valor e controlar o acesso de maneira unificada)

Um bom exemplo pode ser encontrado [neste post do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482351/sharing-data-between-directives) original.

Comment: gostei do exemplo. Muito obrigado pela explicação. Vou dar uma testada em variações desse post do Stack Overflow para ver como posso usar na minha aplicação.

Comment: @Edmo não por isso, é um prazer ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Não é uma boa prática, mas você pode passar a diretiva 1 como required na 1

```
app.directive('directive1', function(){
    return { ... }
});

app.directive('directive2', function) {
    return {
        require: 'directive1',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, directive1Ctrl /* *** AQUI VAI O CONTROLLER DA DIRETIVA1 ** */) {
            // ACESSE A DIRECTIVE 1 PELO QUARTO PARAMETRO PASSADO.
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para você passar valores de `diretivasFilhas` você passa a propriedade para a diretiva que deseja e ela recebe esse valor, exemplo estou passando a propriedade `valor` da *DiretivaA* para a *DiretivaB*, pois irei reaproveitar o que o usuário inseriu neste campo em outro section do meu form. 
Fazendo isso eu posso fazer qualquer regra sem que seja necessário criar um `service` propriamente para isto.

Outra observação eu estou usando AngularJs 1.3 e estou usando `controllerAs` para garantir o escopo, e ao invés de usar $scope eu faço a abordagem do John Papa. (`var $ctrl = this;`)

/* 
   --   diretivaA  --
*/

```
define(['initializer', 'myControllerA'], function (myApp) {
  function myControllerI(ENV) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: ENV.FRONT_END.BASE_URL + '/' + mytemplateA.html,
      controller: 'myControllerA',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        name: '=?',
        zipcode: '=?',
        total: '='
      }
    };
  }

  myApp.directive('directiveA', ['ENV', directiveA]);
});
```

/* 
   --   diretivaB  --
*/

```
define(['initializer', 'myControllerB'], function (myApp) {
  function myControllerB(ENV) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: ENV.FRONT_END.BASE_URL + '/' + mytemplateB.html,
      controller: 'myControllerB',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        car: '=?',
        model: '=?',
        age: '=',
        total: '='  // atributo da minha diretivaA.
      }
    };
  }

  myApp.directive('directiveB', ['ENV', directiveB]);
});
```

/* 
   --   Template Pai  --
  */

```
<div>
    <directive-a 
       name="$ctrl.name"
       zipcode="$ctrl.zipcode"
       total="$ctrl.total">  
     </directive-a>

     <directive-b 
       car="$ctrl.car"
       model="$ctrl.model"
       age="$ctrl.age"
       total="$ctrl.total" (recebendo propriedade da diretivaA)>  
     </directive-b>
</div>
```

References:

1. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html
2. https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/
3. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
4. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/63